# How to sort a list of integers in dart based on their face values?

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

I have tried this

```
void main() {
  final List<String> values= ["1","1000","10","100","200","101","0","100500"];
  values.cast<int>();//change type of list
  values.sort();//sorting function
  print(strikes);//printing output
}
```

in dartpad, and output is like
`[0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 100500, 101, 200]`
but I want
`[0, 1, 10, 100, 101, 200, 1000, 100500]`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `final sorted = values.map(int.parse).toList()..sort(); print(sorted);`

Comment: Thank @pskink for quick and perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program below gives the desired output,
by first parsing each string into integer and getting a list of integers,
then sorting that list of integer and storing it in a variable for further usage.

```
void main() {

  //List to process
  final List<String> values= ["1","1000","10","100","200","101","0","100500"];

  //sorting and storing the above list
  final sorted = values.map(int.parse).toList()..sort();

  //printing the output
  print(sorted);

}
```